# opencsv CSV Reader - Read from specific row onwards.

Tags: java, csv

I've been searching this everywhere, I'm probably just being thick but is there a way to read a csv file from a particular row onwards?  I have a csv file but want to read the data from the 14th row onwards. Below is my csv reader.

```
  CSVReader reader=new CSVReader(new FileReader(filename1));
  String [] value ;

  while((value=reader.readNext())!=null){
```

The data inside the csv is something like this

```
    1   djennings93
    2   27/02/2014
    3   13:31
    ...
    14  26/02/14 14:25:00, www.google.co.uk, 50, Google
```

I'd like to ignore the data from lines 1-13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can skip the first 13 lines by doing:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"), '\t', '\'', 13);
```

Have a look [here](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). (question Can I use my own separators and quote characters?)

This will result in reading the data from the 14th line onward.

Comment: cheers mate! It's amazing what a bit of reading can actually do! my bad.

Comment: What about reading to a specific line. Also as soon as I define `CSVReader reader` is the whole file read? Or the file read happens when I iterate over reader?

Comment: @User3 check section "How do I read and parse a CSV file?" on http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

Boris's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22070419/3292393) still works but [deprecated](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReader.html#CSVReader(java.io.Reader,%20char,%20char,%20char,%20int)). It is recommended to use builder class:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"))
        .withSkipLines(13)
        .withCSVParser(new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator('\t').withEscapeChar('\'').build())
        .build();
```